# Inacessible math mode

Tags: math-mode, luatex

My question concerns `inacessible'. I have already searched and found little information to assist me. My code is much too lengthy and complex for a MWE, so I will have to hunt this down myself. Thus, I seek guidance as to where to look.

The error concerns entrance to math mode. As soon as the `$` is encountered, compile halts, and states that the `$` is inaccessible. Also happens if I use `\(` instead. Does not matter what follows the `$`. Even `$ $` throws the error, as soon as the first `$` is encountered in document body.

I am using lualatex 2017 with fontspec, but the error is not produced by test documents that do not use my code. Thus, the error is certainly in my own code. Also, no error is produced if I avoid math mode, when using my own code. So, that limits the possibilities. I do not have any macros that specifically address math mode.

I have checked, just prior to the `$`, and the catcode of `$` is 3, as expected. I have also asked `\show$` and it tells me that it is the math mode shift, as expected.

According to the TeX error message, and also from previous questions here, `inacessible` may be thrown when the code contains erroneous syntax such as `\def{somecommand}{something}` instead of the correct `\def\somecommand{something}`. I have reviewed my code, and there is no such mistake. The log file does not illuminate me.

So, what other things may cause an `inaccessible` message? Given some possibilities, I will have to hunt this down myself. I hope I have phrased this question so that it is of general interest.

FURTHER EDIT: Earlier, I had a portion of the log file here, but it is too localized to be of general interest. The relevant portion concerned errors in how the math-mode fonts were defined. The errors were always lurking, but not thrown until math mode was entered. What caused the error was my own manipulation of font-related code, in a way that was harmless to ordinary text mode.

I accepted David's answer, because his response (continued in chat) helped me narrow the problem to a particular portion of my code. Barbara's answer was also helpful. When I cut that code section out, math mode works. Now, all I have to do is figure out why. The reason will not be exactly the one mentioned (incorrect usage of `\def`) but rather something involving my own redefinition of a command. There are many ways to fumble a redefinition, which are well-discussed in many other questions on this forum. Among the possibilities are using `\let` when it should be `\LetLtxMacro`, or redefining a command originally in ExplSyntax so that it no longer uses that syntax.

The instructional point: Incorrect usage of `\def` (or `\edef` and such) is not the only way to fumble a macro definition.

FINAL(?) EDIT: Problem solved! In my code, I had done this: `\let\textfont\rmfamily\relax`. That was old code, and I have forgotten why I did it (serves no real purpose). So I got rid of it, and now all is good. It turns out that `\textfontN` (where N is a number) is used by the fontloader. So, my code disrupted the fontloader for whatever followed, and that happened to trap the part where the math font was loaded. The error only appeared when entering math mode, because that was the only place where the misdefined font would be called. If the error had been directly thrown by the fontloader during Preamble, I would have found it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added the final portion of log file, using `\tracingall`.

Comment: Just killed it. It seemed to hang. Will re-try.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Terminated log file with x. Revised final portion of log file now posted above, showing the inacessible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67263/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-robtall).

Comment: `math@fonts ->protect protect edef TU`   you are doomed from here on, this is an accident waiting to happen, I wonder how you got there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an inaccessible control sequence is inserted every math then in classic tex you almost certainly have something like

```
\everymath{\def z{}}


blah $x$

\bye
```

which produces

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
<to be read again> 
                   z
<everymath> \def z
                  {}
<to be read again> 
                   x
l.6 blah $x
           $
?
```

You could do the same in luatex but in luatex there are additional possibilities of inserting the error generating code via Lua callbacks rather than by the `\everymath` register.

---

Since posting this answer the log was added to the question and it confirms that this is essentially what has happened.

LaTeX loads math fonts (the first time math is used at each font size) in `\everymath` and for various reasons it processes font loading code in a mode where backslashes are not used when displaying command names.

For some reason (not clear from the log fragment shown) parts of `\math@fonts` seem to have been incorrectly double-expanded and so the next time it is executed, instead of

```
\def\encoding{TU}
```

it does

```
\def TU{TU}
```

as \encoding has expanded already

so `\def` sees `T` and .....

Comment: None of my own code uses `everymath`. In the log file with `\tracingall` there is only this line: `\everymath->\check@mathfonts \the \everymath `.

Comment: `\show\everymath` produces `toks11`.

Comment: @RobtAll yes I know:-)

Comment: @RobtAll added a start of some analysis of your log

Comment: Add my upvote +1.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I accepted your answer (and related chat) because it has helped me to narrow the error to a particular section of my code. Now I know which island has the buried treasure.

Answer (score 1):

david's comment and answer gave me an idea.

try this with any flavor of latex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{z}{xxx}
\begin{document}
xxx
\end{document}
```

i get

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.2 \newcommand{z}{xxx}
```

this implies the possibility that you may be trying to define a command without an initial backslash.  there are other possibilities, of course, but this should be a relatively easy one to find.

Comment: not the OP: it's Frank that turned off the backslashes then tried to define a command...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- should i delete this answer then?

Comment: no a random future person looking for this error message more likely to be helped by this answer than any answer to the actual problem in this question, which would involve tracing how some unshown lua fot setup in the OPs document has thrown some latex font loading code written in a previous millenium for a different tex engine off course:-)

Comment: Just now, I did look through my code for `\newcommand{missingslash}` but found nothing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Regarding your comment above: In most cases that would be true, but before posting I already found other threads on this topic, including the situation mentioned by yourself and Barbara. The indicated solution did not work. Although the problem is "related" to that, the obscurity of the TeX error message (as usual) provided no guidance.

Comment: @RobtAll the error message isn't that obscure, in fact it identified the error (using `\def` with a letter) and the location fairly exactly. As always with any macro language you have to work back from there to find out what went wrong before expansion lead to that which is probably tricky here but not because the error message is poor.